# Liquid raising SyntaxError in lax mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

I'm trying to set up Liquid gem so that it doesn't raise exceptions on syntax errors. According to the [Liquid gem Readme page](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid#error-modes), you can set different error modes and, if `lax` is set, it should accept "almost anything" and wouldn't raise any exception. Even if I set that mode, an exception is raised, for instance:

```
1.9.3-p551 :041 > Liquid::Template.error_mode = :lax
 => :lax
1.9.3-p551 :042 > Liquid::Template.error_mode
 => :lax
1.9.3-p551 :043 > Liquid::Template.parse("Thank you for your purchase at {{shop_name}")
Liquid::SyntaxError: Liquid syntax error: Variable '{{shop_name}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:104:in `create_variable'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:44:in `parse'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/tag.rb:10:in `parse'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/document.rb:5:in `parse'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:122:in `parse'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:108:in `parse'
    from (irb):43
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing a second `}`.

Instead of

```
Liquid::Template.parse("Thank you for your purchase at {{shop_name}")
```

Try

```
Liquid::Template.parse("Thank you for your purchase at {{shop_name}}")
```

Comment: yes, I know there's a syntax error, what I'm trying to do is configuring Liquid so that it doesn't raise exceptions on those kind of errors. I edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the [expected behavior](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/659#issuecomment-149882458), you can't avoid Liquid raising exceptions in this kind of cases.
(Just in case somebody bumps into the same problem, I'm not closing this question)